# FancyURLopener.version equivalence in requests

Tags: python, url, python-requests, urllib, fancyurlopener

Sometimes it's necessary to change the `version` attribute when retrieving a request using `FancyURLopener`, e.g.

```
from urllib.request import FancyURLopener

class NewOpener(FancyURLopener):
    version = 'Some fancy thing'

url = 'www.google.com'
opener = NewOpener.retrieve(url, 'google.html')
```

Is there an equivalence in the [`requests` library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) when using `requests.get()`?

Comment: Um... I am... really... confused. Do you want to set `User-Agent` in `requests`?

Comment: Is the `FancyURLopener.version` a `User-Agent`? It's just to set an attribute to the opener but honestly, I'm not exactly sure how `FancyURLopener` is treating the `version` attribute. Is it something special?

Comment: According to official doc, `FancyURLopener`'s `version` is inherited from `URLopener`. And `version` in `URLopener` is used to specify "the user agent of the opener object". ref: https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.URLopener.version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Sraw commented, the "version" is basically the `user-agent` file in the header, so

```
requests.get(url, headers={'User-agent': 'Some fancy thing'}
```